# How to use listeners for changing data when I click Next Button In Android?

Tags: android

I am writing a questionairre app in android.

- Question is populated from database
  to textview01 while answers are in
  the form of buttons.
- Buttons are created dynamically for
  each answer based on number of
  answers in the database.Suppose there
  are 4 answers.4 buttons are created.

I am able to do this successfully,there is an image button as well for next.When I press next button i want the question and answers to change.Any hints or previously answered queries on this ?

Basically what i want is a new set of question and answers be delivered on my view everytime next button is pressed.
Regards,
Anderson

Comment: Hmm I don't really understand your problem, but generally speaking, you have to register a ClickListener on the next button and as soon as a ClickEvent is captured you should call the method(s) that query the database for a new question and update the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

its very easy thing.you have to just put onclick listener for all four buttons and on that event you have to set new question text on your textview and answers on your buttons.